# How do the derivatives of the loss function with respect to a layer's inputs form a Jacobian?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, jacobian

Suppose a multi-layer feed-forward neural network, e.g.:

[image: Network Structure]

Using matrix form to account for all training samples $(i)$, the forward propagation can be written as follows:

$Z^{[l]}=W^{[l]}A^{[l-1]}+\overline{b}^{[l]}$

$A^{[l]}=g^{[l]}(Z^{[l]})$

where $g^{[l]}$ is the activation function used at layer ${[l]}$.

Let $L$ denote the loss function. For the backpropagation, we want to compute partial derivatives of $L$ with respect $z^{[l](i)}_j$ for all nodes $j$ of the layer $[l]$ and all training examples $(i)$. Many tutorials (e.g. [this](https://www.jasonosajima.com/backprop)) call the resulting matrix a Jacobian. I do not understand how this is the case.

In particular, we can view $L$ as a function of the inputs at the layer $[l]$, i.e. $L=L(z^{[l]}_1, z^{[l]}_2,\ldots,z^{[l]}_{n^{[l]}})$. For each training sample, the output of this function is a **scalar**, whereas the definition of Jacobian requires that the function's output be a **vector**. So, it seems to me that what we have here (i.e. when we join the derivatives for all the training samples into one matrix form) is not a Jacobian, but a vector of gradients, each computed at a different point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is only one function to evaluate, you'll have one row in the Jacobian matrix, i.e. a vector. For completeness, the following quote is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant):

> Suppose $f : ℝ^n → ℝ^m$ is a function such that each of its first-order partial derivatives exist on $ℝ^n$ ... When m = 1, that is when f : $ℝ^n$ → ℝ is a scalar-valued function, the
> Jacobian matrix reduces to a row vector

Comment: My question was about joining the derivatives for *all the training samples* into one matrix form. Then we get a matrix, not just a row vector. How is that matrix a Jacobian? (I have edited the question to clarify)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning can you point out where the author of the tutorial you linked thinks the Jacobian has different entries for each training example?

Comment: You are correct. When perusing that tutorial (among many others) I missed that he is talking about stochastic updates... In any case, what notation would you use for the matrix I have in mind?

Comment: You don't need to construct such a matrix because gradients for different training examples are averaged (or summed) in backpropagation.

Comment: I would like to derive matrix equations for batch updates of the weights. I would like to do so in matrix form from the beginning to the end, without going first through the derivations for a single training example. This is where the mentioned matrix comes into play.

Comment: Ok, my advice would be concatenating $[J_1,J_2...]$ where $J_i$ is the loss wrt sample $i$, and vectorise your weight matrices (then reshape while updating) so that you don't deal with 3d tensors. The implementation will be quite tricky. You can post it as another question (with your simple example code) after giving some thought maybe.

Comment: I don't understand. The weight matrices stay two-dimensional. It is the delta by which they are updated that depends on all the training samples, but that delta is also a matrix... My question is how to denote the matrix of partial derivatives of the loss with respect to all the inputs, since it is not a Jacobian.